# Lumen file upload testing: file is not present on the request

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

I'm trying to test file upload in Lumen 5.6, but `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` fake doesn't pass checks in my controller. For example:

Test:

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function testUploadImage()
{
    Storage::fake('s3');

    $this->actingAs($this->user)
        ->post('/v1/files', [
            'file1' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg'),
        ])
        ->seeJsonStructure([
            'file1' => [
                'filename',
                'mime',
            ],
        ])
        ->assertResponseStatus(201);

    ...
}
```

Conroller:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file1' => 'required|file|mimetypes:image/jpeg',
    ]);

    // Temp check
    if (!$request->hasFile('file1')) {
        echo 'no file';
    }

    $filename = $request->file('file1')->hashName();
    $mime = $request->file('file1')->getMimeType();

    Storage::disk('s3')
        ->putFile(
            $this->getFolderByMime($mime),
            $request->file('file1'),
            'public'
        );

    return $this->respond([
        'file1' => [
            'filename' => $filename,
            'mime' => $mime,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Validation is passed, but `$request->hasFile('file1')` always returns `false`.

P.S. I use Amazon S3 to store files.

Answer (score 0):

In Lumen the files parameters is hardcoded to empty. [See Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/835).

> This is happening because the files parameter passed to the call
>   method in the post call is hardcoded as an empty array.

You need to structure the call as follows:

```
$this->actingAs($this->user)
    ->post('/v1/files', [], [], [
        'file1' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg'),
    ])
    ->seeJsonStructure([
        'file1' => [
            'filename',
            'mime',
        ],
    ])
    ->assertResponseStatus(201);
```